# Converting 2 line SNP data to 1 line SNP data using R

Tags: r, genetics

So, my problem arises because i am currently working with SNP data received as a .csv file in the following format:

```
alleleID | sample1 | sample2 | sample3
---------------------------------------
    A    |    1    |    0    |    0     
    A    |    0    |    1    |    1      
    B    |    0    |    0    |    1       
    B    |    1    |    1    |    0      
    C    |    1    |    0    |    1      
    C    |    1    |    1    |    1
```

I need to  merge the rows with the same alleleID (so merge row 2 and 3, merge 4 and 5, merge 6 and 7), maintaining the alleleID, but changing the value of the other cells according to the following conditions:
1 and 1 -> 2
0 and 1 -> 1
1 and 0 -> 0 *where the first value is the top row and the second value the bottom row.

The final result should thus be this:

```
alleleID | sample1 | sample2 | sample3
---------------------------------------
    A    |    0    |    1    |    1
    B    |    1    |    1    |    0
    C    |    2    |    1    |    2
```

How can I obtain this with R?

Regards,

Lorenzo

P.S. thanks seb for fixing the table

P.P.S. i have tried a few things in R already, but none worked and I think it would only be confusing to add what I tried so far

Comment: Looks like a new `fizzbuzz` for R programmers. Admittedly it *is* more difficult, though.

Comment: Is the table actual in that format i.e. with `|`, or is it in csv format i.e. comma-separated?

Comment: Hi Vince
The table is a csv file at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Here is procedure I would recommend:

1. Setup a matrix with rows and columns names as AlleleID and sample#, respectively.
2. Initial values of matrix to `0`.
3. Iterate over your data above and use AlleleID and sample# to index the matrix, adding the data value observed to the matrix value.

For example, for AlleleID `C` and Sample `sample1` the matrix value would have the value `1` added twice, thus resulting in matrix value of `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a small function to run your logic - this makes use of 0 and FALSE, and 1 and TRUE

```
fx <- function(x){
  if(x[1] & x[2]) return(2)
  if(!x[1] & x[2]) return(1)
  if(x[1] & !x[2]) return(0)
  return(0)
}
```

And then using dplyr to iterate over the alleles

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(alleleID) %>% summarise_all(fx)
```

If your dataset is huge, there may be faster ways to run this - for example converting the whole dataset to TRUE/FALSE before running it.

You should also check that there two and only two rows for each allele

Perhaps

```
stopifnot(all(table(df$alleleID) == 2))
```

### data

```
df <- read.table(text = "alleleID | sample1 | sample2 | sample3
    A    |    1    |    0    |    0     
    A    |    0    |    1    |    1      
    B    |    0    |    0    |    1       
    B    |    1    |    1    |    0      
    C    |    1    |    0    |    1      
    C    |    1    |    1    |    1 ", header = TRUE, sep = "|")
```